# I am changing a part of an object but it keeps changing all objects in the list without considering the condition set

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, lambda

I am trying to set period number 1 of every Monday of every CourseGroup to true but the object changes all the days instead of only Mondays.Kindly checkout the example below

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Arrays;

import java.util.List;

import java.util.Objects;

class HelloWorld {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SchoolObject schoolObject;
        List<LecturePeriod> lecturePeriods = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            String periodName = "Period " + i;
            int periodNo = i;
            boolean isPeriodAllocated = false;
            lecturePeriods.add(new LecturePeriod(periodName, periodNo, isPeriodAllocated));
        }

        List<Day> days = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            String dayName;
            switch (i) {
                case 1:
                    dayName = "MONDAY";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    dayName = "TUESDAY";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    dayName = "WEDNESDAY";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    dayName = "THURSDAY";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    dayName = "FRIDAY";
                    break;
                default:
                    dayName = "NONE";
            }

            int dayNo = i;
            days.add(new Day(dayName, dayNo, lecturePeriods));
        }

        List<YearGroup> yearGroups = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            int yearGroupNumber = i;
            if (Objects.equals(i, 1)) {
                yearGroups.add(new YearGroup(yearGroupNumber, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new CourseGroup("Science" + 1, days)))));
            } else if (Objects.equals(i, 2)) {
                yearGroups.add(new YearGroup(yearGroupNumber, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new CourseGroup("Science" + 2, days)))));
            } else if (Objects.equals(i, 3)) {
                yearGroups.add(new YearGroup(yearGroupNumber, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new CourseGroup("Science" + 3, days)))));
            }

        }

        schoolObject = new SchoolObject();
        schoolObject.setYearGroups(yearGroups);
        System.out.println("School Object Before Changing Periods="+schoolObject.toString());

        schoolObject.getYearGroups().forEach(yearGroup -> {
            yearGroup.getCourseGroups().forEach(courseGroup -> {
                courseGroup.getDays().forEach(day -> {
                    String dayName = day.getDayName();
                    if (Objects.equals(dayName, "MONDAY")) {
                        day.getLecturePeriods().forEach(lecturePeriod -> {
                            int lecturePeriodNumber = lecturePeriod.getPeriodNumber();
                            if (Objects.equals(lecturePeriodNumber, 1)) {
                                lecturePeriod.setIsPeriodAllocated(true);

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        System.out.println("\nSchool Object After Changing Periods=" + schoolObject.toString());
        final int[] numberOfAllocatedPeriodsExpected = {0};
        schoolObject.getYearGroups().forEach(yearGroup -> {
            yearGroup.getCourseGroups().forEach(courseGroup -> {
                courseGroup.getDays().forEach(day -> {
                    day.getLecturePeriods().forEach(lecturePeriod -> {
                        int lecturePeriodNumber = lecturePeriod.getPeriodNumber();
                        if (Objects.equals(lecturePeriodNumber, 1)) {
                            numberOfAllocatedPeriodsExpected[0]++;
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });


        System.out.println("\nTest result ="+Objects.equals(numberOfAllocatedPeriodsExpected[0],3));

    }




    public static class SchoolObject {
        List<YearGroup> yearGroups;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("SchoolObject{");
            sb.append("yearGroups=").append(yearGroups);
            sb.append('}');
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public List<YearGroup> getYearGroups() {
            return yearGroups;
        }

        public void setYearGroups(List<YearGroup> yearGroups) {
            this.yearGroups = yearGroups;
        }
    }

    public static class YearGroup {

        int yearGroupNumber;
        List<CourseGroup> courseGroups;

        public YearGroup(int yearGroupNumber, List<CourseGroup> courseGroups) {
            this.yearGroupNumber = yearGroupNumber;
            this.courseGroups = courseGroups;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("YearGroup{");
            sb.append("yearGroupNumber=").append(yearGroupNumber);
            sb.append(", courseGroups=").append(courseGroups);
            sb.append('}');
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public int getYearGroupNumber() {
            return yearGroupNumber;
        }

        public void setYearGroupNumber(int yearGroupNumber) {
            this.yearGroupNumber = yearGroupNumber;
        }

        public List<CourseGroup> getCourseGroups() {
            return courseGroups;
        }

        public void setCourseGroups(List<CourseGroup> courseGroups) {
            this.courseGroups = courseGroups;
        }
    }

    public static class CourseGroup {
        String courseGroupName;
        List<Day> days;

        public CourseGroup(String courseGroupName, List<Day> days) {
            this.courseGroupName = courseGroupName;
            this.days = days;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("CourseGroup{");
            sb.append("courseGroupName='").append(courseGroupName).append('\'');
            sb.append(", days=").append(days);
            sb.append('}');
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public List<Day> getDays() {
            return days;
        }

        public void setDays(List<Day> days) {
            this.days = days;
        }

        public String getCourseGroupName() {
            return courseGroupName;
        }

        public void setCourseGroupName(String courseGroupName) {
            this.courseGroupName = courseGroupName;
        }
    }

    public static class Day {
        String dayName;
        int dayNo;
        List<LecturePeriod> lecturePeriods;

        public Day(String dayName, int dayNo, List<LecturePeriod> lecturePeriods) {
            this.dayName = dayName;
            this.lecturePeriods = lecturePeriods;
            this.dayNo = dayNo;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Day{");
            sb.append("dayName='").append(dayName).append('\'');
            sb.append(", dayNo=").append(dayNo);
            sb.append(", lecturePeriods=").append(lecturePeriods);
            sb.append('}');
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public String getDayName() {
            return dayName;
        }

        public void setDayName(String dayName) {
            this.dayName = dayName;
        }

        public int getDayNo() {
            return dayNo;
        }

        public void setDayNo(int dayNo) {
            this.dayNo = dayNo;
        }

        public List<LecturePeriod> getLecturePeriods() {
            return lecturePeriods;
        }

        public void setLecturePeriods(List<LecturePeriod> lecturePeriods) {
            this.lecturePeriods = lecturePeriods;
        }
    }

    public static class LecturePeriod {
        String periodName;
        int periodNumber;
        boolean isPeriodAllocated;

        public LecturePeriod(String periodName, int periodNumber, boolean isPeriodAllocated) {
            this.periodName = periodName;
            this.periodNumber = periodNumber;
            this.isPeriodAllocated = isPeriodAllocated;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("LecturePeriod{");
            sb.append("periodName='").append(periodName).append('\'');
            sb.append(", periodNumber=").append(periodNumber);
            sb.append(", isPeriodAllocated=").append(isPeriodAllocated);
            sb.append('}');
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public String getPeriodName() {
            return periodName;
        }

        public void setPeriodName(String periodName) {
            this.periodName = periodName;
        }

        public int getPeriodNumber() {
            return periodNumber;
        }

        public void setPeriodNumber(int periodNumber) {
            this.periodNumber = periodNumber;
        }

        public boolean isPeriodAllocated() {
            return isPeriodAllocated;
        }

        public void setIsPeriodAllocated(boolean isPeriodAllocated) {
            this.isPeriodAllocated = isPeriodAllocated;
        }
    }
}
```

Observing the output of the data,you notice that the schoolObject set all lecturePeriods to true for all days in each courseGroup instead of only Mondays.
Any help will be much appreciated.
Note:I tried my best to extract the problem to the barest minimum without using gson or jackson which would have allowed a cleaner output when combing through the json generated.
For testing sake,I cramped everything into one class.

You can check the sample here http://ideone.com/3uyE5G

Comment: Do you really need all this code? Can the code and output be broken down a bit more to the essentials? Most people won't look through it all because of the length.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are assigning the same reference of lecture periods for all days:

```
days.add(new Day(dayName, dayNo, lecturePeriods));
```

Because of this, everytime you change a property in the lecturePeriods object in one of the days it will change for all of them. To solve this issue, each day has to have it's own instance of lecturePeriods

```
List<LecturePeriod> lecturePeriods = new ArrayList<>();
for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
    lecturePeriods.add(new LecturePeriod("Period " + j, j, false));
}
days.add(new Day(dayName, dayNo, lecturePeriods));
```

Comment: Hello,@valarauko, thanks for showing me the root cause of the problem.Your diagnosis helped me gain a more scalable solution which I have answered the question now.Thanks a lot for your time.Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

@valarauko,what you showed me was perfectly true,each day had to have it's own instance of lecturePeriods,but a more scalable solution I found was that,since the object could have been initialized in a different number of ways,what I did was

1.Convert the Object into a json String .

2.Convert it back to the original Object before any manipulation.

I used gson for the above two steps and it works perfectly,regardless of how I initialized each day in the schoolObject.

So thanks once again for showing me the root cause @valarauko.